# trying to write Foldtree in Racket n-ary only know how to do write for binary tree

Tags: tree, lisp, racket, fold, arity

I am trying to write a fold command for a tree in DrRacket, only know how to write fo Binary tree.
Have any suggestions how to do it?
It should take a function `f` such as +, - ect. and fold all the given data, but not by flattening the tree.

This is what I've come up with, so far:

```
(define (bt-constr int left right) (list int left right)) 
(define (bt-val tree) (car tree)) 
(define (bt-left tree) (cadr tree)) 
(define (bt-right tree) (caddr tree)) 

(define (bt-fold f int tree)
  (if (null? tree) int 
      (f (bt-val tree) (f (bt-fold f int (bt-left tree)) (bt-fold f int (bt-right tree))))))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following definition,

```
(define (nt-constr int children) (list int children)) 
(define (nt-val tree) (car tree)) 
(define (nt-children tree) (cadr tree))
```

You can follow the same pattern:

```
(define (nt-fold f int tree)
  (if (null? tree) int 
      (f (nt-val tree)
         (... fold the children ...))))
```

Now, you can fold all the children and get a list of their respective "folded values" using `map`,

```
(map (lambda (t) (nt-fold f t)) (nt-children tree))
```

and you can apply the function to this list using `apply`:

```
(define (nt-fold f int tree)
  (if (null? tree) int 
      (f (nt-val tree)
         (apply f (map (lambda (t) (nt-fold f int t)) (nt-children tree))))))
```